# Проблема при установке yii2 шаблона kit-starter

Tags: php, yii2

Выдает ошибку при попытке авторизоваться в админке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Он же по-русски пишет, что не установлено расширение `intl`(php_intl.dll) у *PHP*. То есть его  надо установить в *PHP*.

Если оно уже есть, то скорее всего надо просто в `ini` файле раскоментировать строку:

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Comment: в том то и дело что установлен

Comment: и раскоментированы строки в ini файле?

Comment: да. Я уже перешел на linux и там запустил. Спасибо за ответ